# "Undefined methods for the type "error after importing Netbeans project to Eclipse Pulsar

Tags: java-me, midlet, midp-2.0, cldc

I imported a netbeans project into eclipse ( Pulsar for Mobile Developers.Version: Helios Service Release 1, Build id: 20100917-0705). 
I have two errors multiple times -

1. The method nextInt() in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int)
2. The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) is undefined for the type String

The project works fine in netbeans but I am unable to debug it due to OutOfMemoryError and hence the switch to eclipse.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415778/midp-2-0-version-issues-method-is-undefined-for-type) but it did not solve my problem.

Any other hint to solve this problem ?

- Salil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug on the WTK/eclipse integration https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=315209

Comment: Thanks, but I had seen this link before. I have answered my own question as that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.The method nextInt() in the type Random is not applicable for the
>   arguments (int)
>   2.The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) is undefined for the type String

The above two problems were solved by compiling the code using the latest Nokia S40 SDK.

> The project works fine in netbeans but
>   I am unable to debug it due to
>   OutOfMemoryError and hence the switch
>   to eclipse.

Java Me 3.0 SDK comes installed with NetBeans but it is missing the Java_Platform_ME_SDK.exe found in C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0\toolbar\bin. I had to remove the default J2ME platform ( C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 6.9.1\mobility\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0 ) and add the platform installed here - C:\Java_ME_platform_SDK_3.0.
Using Java_Platform_ME_SDK.exe I increased the emulator heap size to maximum and now I am able to debug my application.

- Salil